# Table in div will change height when I set div width

Tags: html, dojo, height

My html:

A div with `style="position: absolute; top: 3.80711%; left: 5.89354%; height: 20.0508%; width: 20.9125%; z-index: 545;"`

There is a table in above div with style: 
`cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; visibility: visible;" tabindex="0"`

When I change the div width using `dojo.style(divNode, 'width', newvalue)`, the table width will change to a new value accordingly which is correct.

But the table looks higher although the height value is still the old one.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the markup.

Comment: It turns out that there is a padding style in each table cell:
padding: 6.967% 13.933%;

This caused that issue.

Thanks everyone.